# Journey Builder || Object Activity || Save generated SFID

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am using Journey Builder's Object Activity to create a record.
[image]

I am aware that when a record is successfully created, we can get the ID of the new record using the HEALTH option as below,
[image]

But I wish to store this NEWly created ID in a Data Extension against the respective contact.

**So is it possible store using Update contact activity? or any other means?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/how-data-binding-works.html) to get newly created ObjectID and store it in Data Extension using Update Contact activity.
Example of binding string:

`{{Interaction.SALESCLOUDACTIVITY-1.SalesforceObjectID`}}
[image]

The easiest way to find out correct data binding expression is to try setup another Object Activity and select Journey Data Object Activity SalesforceObjectID as attribute:
[image]
Once binding expression recieved it can be used in update activity and the additional object avitivity can be removed.

Comment: Thanks Ros, this is exactly what I was looking into, I will have the verified and confirm back. Many thanks.

Comment: Awesome Ros, this works I have verified it.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score -3):

If you have connected the SF CRM with MC using MC Connect then the ID would be available in the Contact data stream after 15 minutes of sync.

Comment: Yes, we can fetch using Sync Data Extension; but my requirement is to get within journey.

Comment: ok. Can you please elaborate on the use case? Normally you will need to create a custom activity. Else I have an alternate solution if the journey is not sending any emails.